Irreducibility of the $p^k$-th cyclotomic polynomial
I want to prove that the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{p^k}$ is irreducible using Eisenstein (I know that every cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible, I am just trying this approach). I am exposing what I have thought so far. If there is nothing wrong along the way, my question comes at the end, regarding how to deal with the summation that appears, I am not good with calculations :)
We know that $x^{p^k} -1 = \prod_{d | p^k} \Phi_d = \Phi_{1} \Phi_p \Phi_{p^2} \cdots \Phi_{p^k}$
So, isolating $\Phi_{p^k}$, we have:
$$\Phi_{p^k} = \frac{x^{p^k} - 1}{\prod_{d | p^k, d < p^k} \Phi_d}$$
But $\prod_{d | p^k, d < p^k} \Phi_d$ is precisely $x^{p^{k-1}} - 1$.
This simplifies to:
$$\Phi_{p^k} = \frac{x^{p^k} - 1}{x^{p^{k-1}} - 1} = \frac{(x^{p^{k-1}})^p - 1}{x^{p^{k-1}} - 1}$$
Starting from:
$$(a^p - 1) = (a - 1)(a^{p-1} + a^{p-2} + \cdots + 1)$$
Applying this to $a:=x^{p^{k-1}}$, we have:
$$\Phi_{p^k} = \frac{x^{p^k} - 1}{x^{p^{k-1}} - 1} = \frac{(x^{p^{k-1}})^p - 1}{x^{p^{k-1}} - 1} =\frac {(x^{p^{k-1}} - 1)(x^{p^{k-1}(p-1)} + x^{p^{k-1}(p-2)} + \cdots + x^{p^{k-1}} + 1)}{x^{p^{k-1}} - 1}$$
We cancel ${x^{p^{k-1}} - 1}$ and get
$$\Phi_{p^k} = x^{p^{k-1}(p-1)} + \cdots + x^{p^{k-1}} + 1= x^{p^k -p^{k-1}} + x^{p^k -2p^{k-1}}+ \cdots + x^{p^{k-1}} + 1$$
Substituting $x = y + 1$:
$$\Phi_{p^k} = (y+1)^{p^k -p^{k-1}} + (y+1)^{p^k -2p^{k-1}}+ \cdots + (y+1)^{p^{k-1}} + 1$$
This can be represented as:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{p} (y+1)^{p^k - ip^{k-1}} = \sum_{j=0}^{p^k-p^{k-1}} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{p} \binom{p^k - ip^{k-1}}{j} \right) y^j$$
If everything is correct so far, I need to show that p divides every coefficient except the one for $y^{p^k-p^{k-1}}$ and $p^2$ does not divide the coefficient of $y^0$. If we set $k=1$, we can recover the argument for $\Phi_{p}$, so I thought that maybe I could use induction over $k$.
